# jQuery UI Autocomplete with scrollbar z-index help

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, internet-explorer-6, z-index, bgiframe

I have a textbox that I am attaching jQuery UI's Autocomplete functionality to and I am using CSS to give it a max height via the example [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#maxheight).  My problem is that doing this causes the z-index problem that [bgiframe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) solves to come back again, but in a different way.  The initial autocomplete menu is above all the controls underneath it, but when I begin to scroll the autocomplete menu falls behind them.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

This is purely an IE6 bug.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, after scrolling down the autocomplete falls behind the other controls.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the problem by replacing *offsetHeight* by *scrollHeight* in the following line (from jquery.bgiframe.js) :

`height:'+(s.height=='auto'?'expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+\'px\')':prop(s.height))+';'+`

This change solved the bug for the autocomplete fields with vertical scrollbars. I could not spot any regression in other kinds of dialogs (but I did not run extensive tests).

Comment: I opened a bug in bgiframe : http://plugins.jquery.com/content/bgiframe-height-wrong-when-wrapping-div-scrollbars

Comment: when I make this change IE6 freezes on me.  It freezes when I start typing in the Autocomplete Textbox, saying it is loading one of the jQueryUI images it uses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the z-index order of the form elements (or their containers) using javascript. I.e., "Social Worker" has the lowest, "DX Code" the highest z-index.

Comment: the problem is that the autocomplete box is generated dynamically by the jQuery plugin and deals with the z-index on it's own.  I will give this a try though and post results.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change the offsetHeight to scrollHeight, like Siggen says, but I have encountered problems when there is only 1 result returned from the autocomplete.  The 1 result is squished into a window that only like 2 pxs high.
I found a fix though.
When you have a data.length<2, you should use the offsetHeight, rather than the scrollHeight.

You have to modify autocomplete.js.

```
Locate this code:
if($.fn.bgiframe)list.bgiframe();
```

And make it this:

```
if($.fn.bgiframe){
    if(data.length<2)
       list.bgiframe({height:'expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+\'px\')'});
    else 
       list.bgiframe();
}
```

Remember, this code should be used in combination with Siggen's fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a combination of both parameter for the height like this:

`'height:'+(s.height=='auto'?'expression(Math.max(this.parentNode.offsetHeight,this.parentNode.scrollHeight)+\'px\')':prop(s.height))+';'`

Look at the max function. Now it is good with no scroll bar (shorter list and longer list as well)

and now the autocomplete component looks perfect in IE6.