# jquery Autocomplete with bgiframe not working with scrollbars

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, scrollbar, border, bgiframe

Right now I have a text area with autocomplete.  When the autocomplete results come up, the scrollbar and the borders are not being covered by bgiframe.  The border is black.  But on the left the gray is actually from the select box that's below the autocomplete window.

How do I get bgiframe to cover this?
Problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7TLG.jpg

I'm running jquery 1.3.2 min and have the latest bgiframe.  Also, I modified bgiframe for this problem: [offsetHeight to scrollHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674558/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-scrollbar-z-index-help)

```
    autocomplete:
    $('#code').autocomplete(actionurl, {  
                        width: 280,
                        selectFirst: false,
                        matchSubset: false,
                        minChars: 1,
                        max: 100
                    });


    text area:
    <input type="text" id="code" value="" maxlength="10" size="10" name="code"
 autocomplete="off" class="ac_input">
```

Update: I added "$(".ac_results").bgiframe()" to the return jsp of my action and it worked.  However, autocomplete thought that javascript code line was part of my autocomplete results and added a blank line to the result list.  That doesn't look that great.

Update 2: I tried binding "$(".ac_results").bgiframe()" to autocompleteopen and autocompletecreate but those events never fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.  Well, more of a workaround.

The dropbox on the right I switched to a set of radios.

The gray lines on the left of the autocomplete I fixed by adding "margin-left:1px;" to the dropdowns below the autocomplete.